# WSO2 dashboard web socket provider - Failed to load provider configurations

Tags: wso2, siddhi

In wso2 dashboard portal, when I try to create a custom widget using web socket provider, I'm getting "Failed to load provider configuration" error. How to fix this error

[image]

Product : WSO2 Analytic Dashboard
Version : 1.0.0

Network Tab
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the network tab of the browser?

Comment: @Pubci, No I dont see any error there.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when the app cannot reach the backend api. Could you reload and check again?

Comment: this happens at the time of selecting the websocket option. I haven't configured the backend at that time.